# Using php I have trouble with if elseif else statements inside a foreach

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach, replit

Sorry to bother you but i'm a beginner when it comes to coding and i'm kind of stuck.

I've searched the web and tried multiple suggestions (also some of the ones posted here) but it keeps on failing.

### Short description:

I'm working on a project inside **repl.it** -> https://php--olvier79.repl.co
I have an **index.php**
Inside that index.php i have a **foreach loop.**
The foreach loop works fine and prints the output i want on the page after submit.

```
foreach ($_POST as $name => $value)
{
  print "{$name}: {$value}<br />";
}
```

The problems start when i want to clean up the output using if, elseif and else statements;

I've tried multiple suggestions but this is the one i'm currrently stuck with:

```
foreach ($_POST as $name => $value)
  if ($value = "Submit")
  {
    print " Data received Processing";
  }
    elseif ($value = "")
    {
      print "";
    }
      else
      {
        print "{$name}: {$value}<br />";
      }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks so the code can be formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using assignment operators in the conditional statements, while you probably intend to check for equality.

The assignment operator (a single `=`): `$variable = 1`. Means you are assigning the integer `1` to the variable `$variable`.

A comparison operator (double or tripe `=`): `$variable === 1`. Is a statement that evaluates whether the variable `$variable` is (truly) equal to the integer `1`, resulting in a `true` or `false` expression.

So in your code:

```php
if ($value = "Submit") {
   // $value now holds the string "Submit", which is 'truthy', and evaluates to 'true'. This code block will always be executed.
}
```

While you probably intend to:

```php
if ($value === 'Submit') {
   // Execute this code block if $value is truly equal to the string `Submit`.
}
```